# Jquery | How to replace text on json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Im trying to change the '0' to 'changetothis', but its not working.

How can i do that?

http://jsfiddle.net/gnpj5csk/168/

```
var yql_url = 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql';
var url = 'http://***:8080/***.php?username=***&password=***';

$.ajax({
'url': yql_url,
//remove this line later
'data': {
'q': 'SELECT * FROM json WHERE url="'+url+'"',
'format': 'json',
'jsonCompat': 'new',
},
'dataType': 'json',
'success': function(response){
console.log(response);
var res = response.query.results.json;
var keys = Object.keys(res.available_channels);

for(var i =0;i< keys.length;i++){
var tv_archive = res.available_channels[keys[i]].tv_archive;

//i want change 0 if found in tv_archive
var tv_archive = tv_archive.replace("0", "changetothis");

$('#channellist').append(tv_archive+"<br>");
}
}
});
```

Comment: @padusi you are using same variable for both (var tv_archive = res.available_channels[keys[i]].tv_archive;)
and for changed value also you are using this tv_archive. ( var tv_archive = tv_archive.replace("0", "changetothis");)

Comment: like this: https://i.gyazo.com/18a9a616e23715951114c72e11c56fdd.png

Comment: @DhrutikaRathod yes, i tried to change the var name its still dont work with the replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You convert tv_archive to string, after then you can replace, you can't replace because begin tv_archive type integer

```js
var yql_url = 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql';
var url2 = 'http://shipdesk.in/mobile/mobile_quick.php?country=IN&to_country=IN&pin=560001&weight=2.5&unit=KG&need_cod=No&to_pin=700001';
var url ='http://***/***.php?username=***&password=***';

$.ajax({
  'url': yql_url,
  'data': {
    'q': 'SELECT * FROM json WHERE url="'+url+'"',
    'format': 'json',
    'jsonCompat': 'new',
  },
  'dataType': 'jsonp',
  'success': function(response) {
   var res = response.query.results.json;
   var keys = Object.keys(res.available_channels);
    for(var i =0;i< keys.length;i++){
        var tv_archive = res.available_channels[keys[i]].tv_archive;
    tv_archive+="";
       tv_archive = tv_archive.replace("0","changetothis");
      
        $('#channellist').append(tv_archive+"<br>");
  }
     
    
  },
  'error': function(error) {
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "error";
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="channellist"></span>
```